# "Command not found" error in the installation process

Tags: apt, software-installation, makefile

Why I receive the following error while trying to install this package? and how can I resolve it?

```
root@me-System-Product-Name:/home/me/Desktop/mfcuk-master# ls
AUTHORS    configure.ac  INSTALL  Makefile.am  README  TODO
ChangeLog  COPYING       LICENSE  NEWS         src     tools
root@me-System-Product-Name:/home/me/Desktop/mfcuk-master# ./Makefile.am 
./Makefile.am: line 1: SUBDIRS: command not found
./Makefile.am: line 3: style:: command not found
```

Note that I already searched for `SUBDIRS` and `style` packages, but I found nothing.

I also tried `apt-get`, but same result:

```
root@me-System-Product-Name:/home/me/Desktop/mfcuk-master# apt-get install SUBDIRS
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package SUBDIRS
root@me-System-Product-Name:/home/me/Desktop/mfcuk-master# apt-get install style
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package style
```

Comment: `Makefile.am` and `configure.ac` indicate the project uses some of the GNU autotools to install. These files are not to be directly executed. Look at the `README` and `INSTALL` files to see if instructions are given on which commands to run.

Answer (score 0):

`./Makefile.am` is the wrong approach. Start the commands below to build the project:

```
cd /home/me/Desktop/mfcuk-master
automake
autoconf
./configure
make
```

*Running*

```
./mfcuk -C -R 0:A -v 2
```

<sub>[Source](https://github.com/nfc-tools/mfcuk)</sub>